# MySQL join multiple lines

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have database with 2 tables, 1 for storing customers Id and for customer informations. The second table is ordered with key/value because I need to store undefined values.

**Table structure**

*table customers:*

```
=================
    id | status
=================
```

*table customers_info*

```
=======================================
  id | id_customer | key | value
=======================================
```

**Content example:**

*table customers:*

```
=================
    id | status
    1  | 1
    2  | 1
==================
```

*table customers_info*

```
=======================================
    id | id_customer | key | value
    1  | 1           | name| Doe
    2  | 1           | age | 25
    3  | 1           | city| NY
    4  | 2           | name| Smith
=======================================
```

How can I query the tables to dislay all customers with their names

**Example:**

```
=================
    1 | Doe
    2 | Smith
=================
```

If i simply do an inner join I only get first key of the table:

```
SELECT * FROM customers inner join customers_info on customers.id = customers_info.id_customer
```

Comment: What does the id column in customers_info do?

Comment: Nothing, just to have primary key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ci.id_customer AS CustomerId, ci.value AS CustomerName
FROM customers_info ci 
WHERE ci.key = 'name'
ORDER BY ci.id_customer;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eef5ce/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| CUSTOMERID | CUSTOMERNAME |
|------------|--------------|
|          1 |          Doe |
|          2 |        Smith |
```

**::EDIT::**

To get all fields for customers

```
SELECT ci.id_customer AS CustomerId, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ci.key = 'name' THEN ci.value ELSE '' END) AS CustomerName, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ci.key = 'age' THEN ci.value ELSE '' END) AS CustomerAge, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ci.key = 'city' THEN ci.value ELSE '' END) AS CustomerCity
FROM customers_info ci 
GROUP BY ci.id_customer
ORDER BY ci.id_customer;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eef5ce/4)

**OUTPUT**

```
| CUSTOMERID | CUSTOMERNAME | CUSTOMERAGE | CUSTOMERCITY |
|------------|--------------|-------------|--------------|
|          1 |          Doe |          25 |           NY |
|          2 |        Smith |             |              |
```

**::EDIT::**

To Fetch the GENDER from gender table:

```
SELECT a.CustomerId, a.CustomerName, a.CustomerAge, a.CustomerCity, g.name AS CustomerGender
FROM (SELECT ci.id_customer AS CustomerId, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN ci.key = 'name' THEN ci.value ELSE '' END) AS CustomerName, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN ci.key = 'age' THEN ci.value ELSE '' END) AS CustomerAge, 
             MAX(CASE WHEN ci.key = 'city' THEN ci.value ELSE '' END) AS CustomerCity
      FROM customers_info ci 
      GROUP BY ci.id_customer
     ) AS a
INNER JOIN customers c ON a.CustomerId = c.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN gender g ON C.genderId = c.id 
ORDER BY a.CustomerId;
```

Comment: Is always any way to gey all fields for customers, for exemple get name and age for each customer?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Many thanks this is what I want!

Comment: And how can I join another table? For example Id like to display customer family. I have row gender in customers and I need to display gender name from gender table.
So I would like to have this:

| CUSTOMERID | CUSTOMERNAME | CUSTOMERAGE | CUSTOMERCITY |GENDER
|------------|--------------|-------------|--------------|
|          1 |          Doe |          25 |           NY |MALE

In T. customers I have gender row, So I need to join customers_info with customers and join genders with customers.In customers table I have gender id In gender table id 1 is male and id 2 is female. Hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.id as 'customer id', info.value as 'Customer Name'
FROM customers c JOIN customer_info info 
ON c.id = info.id_customer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_customer, value FROM customers_info WHERE key LIKE 'name'
```

Comment: If the OP just wants the customer id and customer name (which it appears he does) then this is by far the simplest way to solve that. Good first post :)

Answer (score 0):

use Inner join or join for intersect result.. // inner join and join both are identical

Try this

```
SELECT c.id as 'Id', i.value as 'Name'
FROM customers c INNER JOIN customer_info AS i 
ON c.id = i.id_customer 

// OR

SELECT c.id as 'Id', i.value as 'Name'
FROM customers c INNER JOIN customer_info AS i 
ON c.id = i.id_customer
GROUP BY i.id_customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select ci.value
from customers_info ci
INNER JOIN customers c 
    ON c.id = ci.id_customer
WHERE ci.key IN ['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eav_hell;

CREATE TABLE eav_hell
(id_customer INT NOT NULL
,attribute VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id_customer,attribute)
);

INSERT INTO eav_hell VALUES
(1,'name','Doe'),
(1,'age',25),
(1,'city','NY'),
(2,'name','Smith');

SELECT id_customer 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'name' THEN value END) name 
  FROM eav_hell 
 GROUP 
    BY id_customer;
+-------------+-------+
| id_customer | name  |
+-------------+-------+
|           1 | Doe   |
|           2 | Smith |
+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id,t2.key1 from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on  
t1.id=t2.id_customer group by t2.key1,t1.id  
having t2.key1 in ('name')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8369f/37)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it too complicated. Just simple as it goes:

```
SELECT C.`id`, CI.`value` from customers_info CI
JOIN customers C ON = CI.`id_customer` = C.`id`
WHERE CI.`key` = 'name'
ORDER BY CI.`id_customer`;
```